# mongodb querying regex with casbah fluid syntax

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I am having an issue with querying against a regex with fluid dsl syntax, i am trying to say something like `("id" -> foo)` using fluid. foo is a regex, so there is no $elemMatch on regex so I am getting "No implicit view available from Regex to DBObject".

so, currently i have to structure my query in the following way:

`("someval" $gte 5) ++ ("id" -> foo)`, I have to put id portion on the end because it's not going through the dsl. What I would like is something like

```
("id" [WHAT OP HERE?] foo.r) ++ ("someval" $gte 5)
```

How do i accomplish this?
Please note that I know how to use "regular" ("foo" -> MongoDbObject(... syntax, I would like to use the dsl to do the same thing.

Thanks!

Comment: Regular variant is `MongoDBObject("id" -> foo.r) ++ ("someval" $gte 5)` and I don't know simpler if you want id in the beginning.

Comment: you can create alias, for example `val $ = MongoDBObject` and use it as `$("foo" -> "bar".r) ++ ("someval" $gte 5)`

Comment: @SergeyPassichenko i don't understand why there is no $eq? i thought at first i was not finding it, and searched through all the code :), there is a $neq with regex, so doesn't it make sense to do $eq with regex? maybe i am not understanding something

Comment: @SergeyPassichenko btw, klassnij blog :)

Comment: Sometimes I think that $eq operator will be usable, but it's not critical for me :) May be you should ask about it in casbah user group or create an issue.

Comment: It's our company blog, I'm glad that you liked it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't just an issue for regular expressions but for any fluid syntax that does an equality measure eg:

```
("name" -> "rozza") ++ ("forum" -> "stackoverflow")
```

This also fails, currently you have to wrap in a `MongoDBObject` instance.

Comment: so, the issue is really that ("name" -> "rozza") is the tuple that MongoDbObject expects, but not the MongoDbObject itself that the ++ operator is on, so your example would work if you changed the tuples to MongoDbObjects

Comment: If this is the correct answer - please mark it as so to help others